# vuejs remove key and value from URL based on conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am making a simple filter and In this filter I am pushing query parameters to URL and appending them. If user choose a particular option, I want to modify the query string and I need the help here.

My URL is like this : http://app.test/home?preference=onsite&place=Aus&place=Mus

and if user choose `wfh` instead of `onsite` for `preference` I want to remove place from URL and want this URL: http://app.test/home?preference=wfh

my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="mt-2">
         
        </div>

        <div class="mt-2" v-if=" this.$route.query.preference == 'onsite'">
            <label>Available for work</label>
            <div class="form-control" >
                <input type="text">
                <div class="options" style="max-height:140px;overflow:scroll">
                    <ul class="" style="max-height:40px;">
                        
                        <li v-for="place in places" :key="place.id">
                           <input type="checkbox" v-model="filter.place" 
                           :value="place.name">{{ place.name }}
                        </li>
                    
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            places: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "Aus",
                    },

                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Mus",
                    }, 
            ],

            filter: {
                preference: this.$route.query.preference,
                place:[],
            },
        };
    },

    watch: {
        filter: {
            handler() {
                const query = this.filter
             
                    
                this.$router.push({
                    query: query,
                });
                
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I wrote below code to check if preference is wfh and update URL but this is not working

```
  if (this.$route.query.preference == 'wfh') {
     this.$route.query.place='';
     this.$router.replace({ query: query });
   }
```

Comment: can you directly use this.$router.push and update the URL w/o using replace?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the rest of the queries and `replace` with them, it same like delete `place` query.

```
if (this.$route.query.preference == 'wfh') {
 const { place, ...query} = this.$route.query;
 this.$router.replace({ query: query });
```

}

Comment: I changed it , but noting happened, place is not removed from URL if the preference is wfh

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code on a live editor like codesandbox, so we can debug?

Comment: Hi,  It uses vue-router, I am not sure how to use vue router in code sandbox so it shows error: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-sky-wwm1k6?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Which version of vue you are using? 2 or 3?

Comment: Also which version of vue-router you are using in your project, you can have a look at `package.json` file to see the versions.

Comment: I using vue js 3

Comment: Please provide the full version of vue and vue-router that exist in the `package.json`

Comment: "vue-router": "^4.1.1"
  "vue": "^3.2.36",

Comment: I just set the vue-router for you, you can use this repo. https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-darkness-ulgoh9

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-sky-wwm1k6?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Hi mina thanks that worked it removed from URL but one problem, when I again change from wfh to onsite , previous place value is pushed to URL and place checkbox are also checked